# List of Kubernetes status conditions for jobs?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

Is there any resource out there that gives an overview of all the possible status conditions a kubernetes job can have?

I'm wondering because I would like to check, when I run a job if it is already running and if so, exit the new job.

I came across `until kubectl get jobs myjob -o jsonpath='{.status.conditions[?(@.type=="Complete")].status}' | grep True ; do sleep 1 ; done` quite a few times but I want to know if it is running, not if it is already complete. Would prefer not to wait (ha) for kubectl 1.11 wait functionality

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The [kubernetes API docs for JobCondition](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.18/#jobcondition-v1-batch) imply that the only `type` values are “Complete” and “Failed”, and that they may have a `”True”` or `”False”` `status`.

In addition to the job status conditions array, you may also find it informative to look at the job status `active` count, and the `startTime` and `completionTime` if you’re just interested in whether it’s finished.

Comment: What does status "True" or "False" mean? `completionTime` time is not populated if the job finished unsuccessfully, so it is not very useful for determining if the job has finished.

Answer (score 4):

```
kubectl get jobs <myjob> --namespace <mynamespae> -o jsonpath='{.status.conditions[?(@.type=="Succeeded")].status}'
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe this can help to get all job statuses for a given selector and after the result can be parsed in bash or CI to wait until some specific statuses:

```
kubectl get job -n myspace --selector=appName=myapplication -o json | jq -r '.items[] | .metadata.name + ":" + (.status.conditions[] | select(.status == "True") .type + ":" + .status)'
myapplication-job-1558097758:Complete:True
myapplication-job-1558101228:Failed:True
```

Also here I found another example for bash:

[Wait for kubernetes job to complete on either failure/success using command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55073453/wait-for-kubernetes-job-to-complete-on-either-failure-success-using-command-line#comment97122458_55077916)

By @ruazn2:

```
until [[ $SECONDS -gt $end ]] || [[ $(kubectl get jobs $job_name -o jsonpath='{.status.conditions[?(@.type=="Failed")].status}') == "True" ]] || [[ $(kubectl get jobs $job_name -o jsonpath='{.status.conditions[?(@.type=="Complete")].status}') == "True" ]]; do
```

Comment: This was the most useful answer of the three so far for me.

Answer (score 1):

This one has been successfully tested and returns "True" or "False":

```
kubectl get jobs <myjob> --namespace <mynamespace> -o jsonpath='{.status.conditions[?(@.type=="Complete")].status}'
```

Comment: almost exactly what I wanted, all I care is the status, so `-o=jsonpath='{.status.conditions[].type}'`. thank you for this

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if anyone else had the same trouble as me... Here's something you can pipe through `xargs` and operate on. This outputs all failed jobs:

```bash
kubectl get jobs \
    -n [your namespace] \
    -o jsonpath='{range .items[?(.status.failed == 1)]} {.metadata.name}{"\n"} {end}'
```

And an explanation...

- `-n` is the namespace you're searching
- `-o` specifies the format of your output
- `range [iterable]` specifies that you want to loop over something. It goes in curly braces `{range [iterable]}` and must have an `{end}` at the end. Range lets you operate on each item over which you're iterating, so between `range` and `end` you're working with the individual items.
- `.items[*]` would return all items in the json output given by `kubectl get job [job name] -n [namespace] -o json`, and wow, what a handy reference that is. This is where you'll find all the paths to items in the job description.
- `?()` let's you FILTER. This is the really powerful bit. If something matches the condition then it's included in the result
- `?(.status.failed == 1)` specifies that we want to include all results that have a status of "failed"... that's those results that have json path `.status.failed` set to `1`.
- `.metadata.name` specifies that we want to output the name of the job we're matching.
- `"\n"` says to add a newline between matched jobs.

Here's a reference if you want to learn more: https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/jsonpath/