# Wait for kubernetes job to complete on either failure/success using command line

Tags: kubernetes, wait, jobs, kubectl, kubernetes-jobs

What is the best way to wait for kubernetes job to be complete?  I noticed a lot of suggestions to use:

```
kubectl wait --for=condition=complete job/myjob
```

but i think that only works if the job is successful. if it fails, i have to do something like:

```
kubectl wait --for=condition=failed job/myjob
```

is there a way to wait for both conditions using wait?  if not, what is the best way to wait for a job to either succeed or fail?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`kubectl wait --for=condition=<condition name` is waiting for a specific condition, so afaik it can not specify multiple conditions at the moment.

My workaround is using `oc get --wait`, `--wait` is closed the command if the target resource is updated. I will monitor `status` section of the job using `oc get --wait` until `status` is updated. Update of `status` section is meaning the Job is complete with some status conditions.

If the job complete successfully, then `status.conditions.type` is updated immediately as `Complete`. But if the job is failed then the job pod will be restarted automatically regardless `restartPolicy` is `OnFailure` or `Never`. But we can deem the job is `Failed` status if not to updated as `Complete` after first update.

Look the my test evidence as follows.

- Job yaml for testing successful complete

```
    # vim job.yml
    apiVersion: batch/v1
    kind: Job
    metadata:
      name: pi
    spec:
      parallelism: 1
      completions: 1
      template:
        metadata:
          name: pi
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: pi
            image: perl
            command: ["perl",  "-wle", "exit 0"]
          restartPolicy: Never
```

- It will show you `Complete` if it complete the job successfully.

```
    # oc create -f job.yml &&
      oc get job/pi -o=jsonpath='{.status}' -w &&
      oc get job/pi -o=jsonpath='{.status.conditions[*].type}' | grep -i -E 'failed|complete' || echo "Failed" 

    job.batch/pi created
    map[startTime:2019-03-09T12:30:16Z active:1]Complete
```

- Job yaml for testing failed complete

```
    # vim job.yml
    apiVersion: batch/v1
    kind: Job
    metadata:
      name: pi
    spec:
      parallelism: 1
      completions: 1
      template:
        metadata:
          name: pi
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: pi
            image: perl
            command: ["perl",  "-wle", "exit 1"]
          restartPolicy: Never
```

- It will show you `Failed` if the first job update is not `Complete`. Test if after delete the existing job resource.

```
    # oc delete job pi
    job.batch "pi" deleted

    # oc create -f job.yml &&
      oc get job/pi -o=jsonpath='{.status}' -w &&
      oc get job/pi -o=jsonpath='{.status.conditions[*].type}' | grep -i -E 'failed|complete' || echo "Failed" 

    job.batch/pi created
    map[active:1 startTime:2019-03-09T12:31:05Z]Failed
```

I hope it help you. :)

Comment: i ended up just making a simple script to check the status as you had shown:

`until [[ $SECONDS -gt $end ]] || [[ $(kubectl get jobs $job_name -o jsonpath='{.status.conditions[?(@.type=="Failed")].status}') == "True" ]] || [[ $(kubectl get jobs $job_name -o jsonpath='{.status.conditions[?(@.type=="Complete")].status}') == "True" ]]; do`

Comment: That's great, and I'm sorry for showing the `openshift cli` example. But you can catch up as `kubernetes cli`, it's great !

Comment: actually there is no --wait and -w does stand for --watch

Answer (score 44):

Run the first wait condition as a subprocess and capture its PID. If the condition is met, this process will exit with an exit code of 0.

```bash
kubectl wait --for=condition=complete job/myjob &
completion_pid=$!
```

Do the same for the failure wait condition. The trick here is to add `&& exit 1` so that the subprocess returns a non-zero exit code when the job fails.

```bash
kubectl wait --for=condition=failed job/myjob && exit 1 &
failure_pid=$!
```

Then use the Bash builtin `wait -n $PID1 $PID2` to wait for one of the conditions to succeed. The command will capture the exit code of the first process to exit:

> MAC USERS! Note that `wait -n [...PID]` requires Bash version 4.3 or higher. MacOS is forever stuck on version 3.2 due to license issues. Please see this [Stackoverflow Post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11704224/3745474) on how to install the latest version.

```bash
wait -n $completion_pid $failure_pid
```

Finally, you can check the actual exit code of `wait -n` to see whether the job failed or not:

```bash
exit_code=$?

if (( $exit_code == 0 )); then
  echo "Job completed"
else
  echo "Job failed with exit code ${exit_code}, exiting..."
fi

exit $exit_code
```

Complete example:

```bash
# wait for completion as background process - capture PID
kubectl wait --for=condition=complete job/myjob &
completion_pid=$!

# wait for failure as background process - capture PID
kubectl wait --for=condition=failed job/myjob && exit 1 &
failure_pid=$! 

# capture exit code of the first subprocess to exit
wait -n $completion_pid $failure_pid

# store exit code in variable
exit_code=$?

if (( $exit_code == 0 )); then
  echo "Job completed"
else
  echo "Job failed with exit code ${exit_code}, exiting..."
fi

exit $exit_code
```

Comment: You can use `if wait ...` instead of storing exit code in a variable.

Comment: @Exagone313 You're right - in the original script I was using trap so I was using the exit code elsewhere.

Comment: `wait -n` is not available on MacOS :(

Comment: make sure you don't have "set -e" on! otherwise the `wait -n ` command will exit straight away if the failure_pid wins, and you won't get your nice `if` statement logging. Apart from that, this approach worked perfectly

Answer (score 11):

You can leverage the behaviour when `--timeout=0`.

In this scenario, the command line returns immediately with either result code 0 or 1. Here's an example:

```
retval_complete=1
retval_failed=1
while [[ $retval_complete -ne 0 ]] && [[ $retval_failed -ne 0 ]]; do
  sleep 5
  output=$(kubectl wait --for=condition=failed job/job-name --timeout=0 2>&1)
  retval_failed=$?
  output=$(kubectl wait --for=condition=complete job/job-name --timeout=0 2>&1)
  retval_complete=$?
done

if [ $retval_failed -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "Job failed. Please check logs."
    exit 1
fi
```

So when either `condition=failed` or `condition=complete` is true, execution will exit the while loop (`retval_complete` or `retval_failed` will be `0`).

Next, you only need to check and act on the condition you want. In my case, I want to fail fast and stop execution when the job fails.

Answer (score 9):

The `wait -n` approach does not work for me as I need it to work both on Linux and Mac.

I improved on the answer provided by Clayton a little, because his script would not work with `set -e -E` enabled. The following will work even in that case.

```sh
while true; do
  if kubectl wait --for=condition=complete --timeout=0 job/name 2>/dev/null; then
    job_result=0
    break
  fi

  if kubectl wait --for=condition=failed --timeout=0 job/name 2>/dev/null; then
    job_result=1
    break
  fi

  sleep 3
done

if [[ $job_result -eq 1 ]]; then
    echo "Job failed!"
    exit 1
fi

echo "Job succeeded"
```

You might want to add a timeout to avoid the infinite loop, depends on your situation.

Comment: I would ask why would it be not sufficient to just use `set -e` and that would identify for error command. Then I wont need to check for failed condition ?? @Martin Melka

Comment: When you call `kubectl wait --for=condition=failed --timeout=0 job/name` and the status of the pod is _not_ `failed`, then that command exits with a nonzero exit code. With `set -e` enabled, that will cause the whole script to terminate. The logic here is that "while `kubectl wait` exits with nonzero code, keep polling it". We only want the script to exit when `kubectl wait` exits with a zero exit code, because that means the pod is either completed or failed.

Comment: but pod status generally lands on "error"   like 0/1 (error)   so possibly in the `first`  failed job set -e would exit the script out correct ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow what you mean. The `kubectl wait` doesn't exit with the exit code of the pod status. `kubectl wait --for=condition=complete --timeout=0 job/name ` will exit with 0 (success) if the pod is _currently_ in a completed (successful) state. 1 (error) otherwise (that is, if the pod is _currently_ still running/pending/failed/whatever). Similarly, `kubectl wait --for=condition=failed --timeout=0 job/name ` will exit with 0 (success) if the pod is currently in a failed state. It's done this way because there is no `kubectl` cmd to do "exit when the pod is success or error".

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following workaround using `kubectl logs --follow`:

```
kubectl wait --for=condition=ready pod --selector=job-name=YOUR_JOB_NAME --timeout=-1s
kubectl logs --follow job/YOUR_JOB_NAME
```

It will terminate when your job terminates, with any status.

Comment: It doesn't work for jobs with multiple containers.

Comment: Found a solution for "multiple containers in a single job" case - you should add flag `--all-containers=true` to `kubectl logs` command

Comment: tested, it exits after the first container completes, not applicable for initContainer + container; --pod-running-timeout=40s --ignore-errors=true not helps

Comment: Your tip also works for standalone pods outside a job

Comment: `kubectl logs` has an option `--pod-running-timeout` which seems to replace the first command -- and doesn't hang if the pod never comes up.

Comment: It also doesn't seem to work. Never mind. :/ 

Unfortunately, `logs` seems to terminate _before_ the job switches its status to either `succeeded` or `failed`. So we have to wait _again_ before being able to access the result. Square 1!

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did. I label my jobs so that I can use the labels to find them. I wait for the labeled job(s) to have status.ready=0

```
k wait -l label=value --for=jsonpath='{.status.ready}'=0 job
```

You can then use the following to find out if the first job in the items returned by the labels failed

```
failed=$(k get jobs -l label=value -o jsonpath={.items[0].status.failed})
exit ${failed}
```