# Kuebctl wait for multiple jobs completion (fail or success)

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I want to wait for multiple jobs which can fail or succeed. I wrote a simple script based on an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55073453/wait-for-kubernetes-job-to-complete-on-either-failure-success-using-command-line) from Sebastian N. It's purpose is to wait for either success or fail of a job. The script works fine for **one** job (it can only fail or success obviously).

Now for the problem... I need to wait for **multiple** jobs identified by the same label. The script works fine when all jobs fail or all jobs succeed. But when some job fails, some succeeds the *kubectl wait* will time out.

For what I intend to do next it's not necessary to know which jobs failed or succeeded I just want to know when they end. Here is the "wait part" of the script I wrote (LABEL is the label by which the jobs I want to wait for are identified):

```
kubectl wait --for=condition=complete -l LABEL --timeout 14400s && exit 0 &
completion_pid=$!

kubectl wait --for=condition=failed -l LABEL --timeout 14400s && exit 1 &
failure_pid=$!

wait -n $completion_pid $failure_pid
exit_code=$?

if (( exit_code == 0 )); then
  echo "Job succeeded"
  pkill -P $failure_pid
else
  echo "Job failed"
  pkill -P $completion_pid
fi
```

If someone is curious why I kill the other *kubectl wait* command it's because of the timeout I set. When  the job succeeds the process ends but the other one waits until the time out is reached. To stop running it on the background I simply kill it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround that fits my purpose. I found out that *kubectl logs* with the *--follow* or *-f* flag pointed to */dev/null* actually "waits" until all jobs are done.

Further explanation:

The *--follow* flag means that the logs are printed continuously - not looking at the finishing state of the job. In addition, pointing the logs to */dev/null* doesn't leave any unwanted text. I needed to print the output of logs via Python so I added another *kubectl logs* at the end (which I think is not ideal but it serves the purpose). I use sleep because I assume there is some procedure after all jobs are completed - without it the logs are not printed. Finally I use *--tail=-1* flag because my logs are expected to have large output.

Here is my updated script (this part replaces everything from the script specified in question):

```
#wait until all jobs are completed, doesn't matter if failed or succeeded
kubectl logs -f -l LABEL > /dev/null

#sleep for some time && print final logs
sleep 2 && kubectl logs -l LABEL --tail=-1
```