# Kubectl command to wait for Pod termination which fails fast

Tags: kubectl

I have a test that launches a Pod to check that certain functionality exists within the cluster.

I want to launch the Pod with `kubectl create` then `kubectl wait` to get the container's exit code to determine the test's successfulness, with a fail-fast approach. I'm interested in pure `kubectl` solutions, as this is the portable unit between the test environments (shell scripts vary).

Other similar posts' answers assume that the Pod will succeed, so either use wait with:

- `--for jsonpath` to check `{.status.phase}=Succeeded`
- `--for condition=Completed` and wrap the Pod in a Job

The problem is that, if the test fails it waits for the full `--timeout`, which in my case can be a long time - time, resources and energy that are wasted if the Pod fails early.

I've explored using:

- Any `or` conditionals, wait accepts multiple `--for` arguments, but only considers the final one
- `--for jsonpath='{.status.conditions[...].reason}'=PodCompleted`, which doesn't work in a variety of formulations tried because can't filter to an individual .reason, or .reason doesn't exist immediately and results in an early error.
- `--for jsonpath='{.status.containerStatuses[0].state.terminated}` as there's no field here that has an exact value to check against; there's no way to test for the presence of keys

Thanks

Comment: Check these answers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55073453/wait-for-kubernetes-job-to-complete-on-either-failure-success-using-command-line

Comment: Thanks @RudyS, I had not seen this relevant post. Most of the answers rely on shell scripting and I'm looking for something that works inherently across platforms. I had tried the one that doesn't, https://stackoverflow.com/a/72900831/14693713, and it didn't work for my case in the end but I can't remember why not, so I'll give it another go :)